# What happens when a fortified land stops being a land?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Darksteel Garrison](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Darksteel%20Garrison) is like an equipment but for land - it can fortify a land, giving it an extra ability. The [Westvale Abbey](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Westvale%20Abbey) is a land but once it transforms, it's no longer a land.

What happens when a land such as [Westvale Abbey](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Westvale%20Abbey) equipped with a [Darksteel Garrison](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Darksteel%20Garrison) transforms?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When the fortified land stops being a land, the fortification unattaches.
From Magic Comprehensive Rules (emphases mine):

> **301.5c** An Equipment that’s also a creature can’t equip a creature. An Equipment that loses the subtype “Equipment” can’t equip a creature. An Equipment can’t equip itself. **An Equipment that equips an illegal or nonexistent permanent becomes unattached from that permanent** but remains on the battlefield. (This is a state-based action. See rule 704.) An Equipment can’t equip more than one creature. If a spell or ability would cause an Equipment to equip more than one creature, the Equipment’s controller chooses which creature it equips.
>
> **301.6.** Some artifacts have the subtype “Fortification.” A Fortification can be attached to a land. It can’t legally be attached to an object that isn’t a land. Fortification’s analog to the equip keyword ability is the fortify keyword ability. **Rules 301.5a–e apply to Fortifications in relation to lands just as they apply to Equipment in relation to creatures**, with one clarification relating to rule 301.5c: a Fortification that’s also a creature (not a land) can’t fortify a land. (See rule 702.66, “Fortify.”)